# Angular animations is not letting a component to get destroyed when it should

Tags: angular-animations

When an animation is dependent on query params, it somehow gets precedence over anything else. I'll link a Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2lmak?file=src%2Fmain.ts), where it's by far easiest to see what's happening.

This is a simple example to illustrate the problem, the app I'm building is far more complicated, but this is what everything boils down to.

In angular animations, a parent animation always takes precedence over a child animation (or at least, it should?).

So, in the parent component, I've created an animation, that animates a little when my query params change. It also has `animateChild()`, because a lot of the time in my real app, I want the children to animate at the same time. That doesn't happen in this minimal example though, it only shows the problems.

In the bar component, when changing query params, an animation also happens. No problem so far.

When changing between routes `/foo`and `/bar`, in case there's no change in query params, everything works fine.

**The problem** arises when going from `/bar?show=HERPDERP` to `/foo`. The animation inside bar component want's to run before letting the bar component to get destroyed. For a while, both foo and bar are visible, which is not what I want. For some reason, bar doesn't get destroyed when the inner animation is finished, it waits before the whole `@parentAnimation`is finished.

I want bar to get destroyed instantly, so I created one more animation, `@blockContent`, that should run every time query params change, where `animateChild()` is **not** activated. It prevents the contained animations to run on `:enter`, but for some reason it doesn't block them when query params change. It *does* work if the bar component is inserted as `<bar *ngIf="route='bar'"></bar>`, but now it's inserted through a `router-outlet (which it needs to be). If I disable the inner animation (`@fadeInAndOut`) or` @parentAnimation`, it works. It also works if I disable` animateChild()` in parent animation. It's only when both are combined that the problem arises.

Why is this happening, and what can be done about it, except not having these animations?

---

Here is the relevant source code for future reference, in case the Stackblitz link stops working:

**Parent component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: `parent`,
  template: `
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div [@parentAnimation]="(queryParams['show'] ?? '').length" class="parent">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <button [routerLink]="['/parent', 'foo']">TO FOO</button>
    <button [routerLink]="['/parent', 'bar']">TO BAR</button>
  `,
  standalone: true,
  animations: [parentAnimation],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
  ],
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  route = inject(ActivatedRoute);
  queryParams: Params;
  queryParamsSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.queryParamsSubscription = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
      (queryParams) => {
        this.queryParams = queryParams;
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.queryParamsSubscription) {
      this.queryParamsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

**Foo component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  templateUrl: `
    <div class="foo">
    <h6>FOO</h6>
    </div>
  `,
  standalone: true,
})
export class FooComponent {}
```

**Bar component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: `bar`,
  template: `
    <div class="bar">
      <h6>BAR</h6>
      <div [@blockContent]="(queryParams['show'] ?? '').length">
        <p @fadeInAndOut *ngIf="queryParams['show']">Query params: {{queryParams['show']}}</p>
      </div>
      <button [routerLink]="[]" [queryParams]="{ show: 'HERPDERP' }">create query params</button>
    </div>
  `,
  standalone: true,
  animations: [fadeInAndOut, blockContent],
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
})
export class BarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  route = inject(ActivatedRoute);
  queryParams: Params;
  queryParamsSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.queryParamsSubscription = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
      (queryParams) => {
        this.queryParams = queryParams;
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.queryParamsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**Animations:**

```
export const fadeInAndOut = trigger(`fadeInAndOut`, [
  transition(`:enter`, [
    style({ opacity: 0 }),
    animate(`500ms`, style({ opacity: 1 })),
  ]),
  transition(`:leave`, [animate(`500ms`, style({ opacity: 0 }))]),
]);

export const parentAnimation = trigger(`parentAnimation`, [
  transition(`:increment`, [
    style({ transform: `translateY(0rem)` }),
    group([
      sequence([
        animate(`1s`, style({ transform: `translateY(-10rem)` })),
        animate(`1s`, style({ transform: `translateY(0)` })),
      ]),
      query(`*`, animateChild(), { optional: true }),
    ]),
  ]),
  transition(`:decrement`, [
    style({ transform: `translateY(0rem)` }),
    group([
      sequence([
        animate(`1s`, style({ transform: `translateY(10rem)` })),
        animate(`1s`, style({ transform: `translateY(0)` })),
      ]),
      query(`*`, animateChild(), { optional: true }),
    ]),
  ]),
]);

export const blockContent = trigger(`blockContent`, [
  transition(`* => *`, []),
]);
```

**Routes:**

```
export const buggyAppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ``,
    redirectTo: `parent`,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    },
  {
    path: `parent`,
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: `foo`,
        component: FooComponent,
      },
      {
        path: `bar`,
        component: BarComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```